# c++ restore sql server database - database stuck in "restoring..." state

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, odbc

I have some c++ code that restores a sql server database via sql.  It seems to frequently leave the database stuck in the "restoring..." state.

I seem to be able to work around this by introducing a 3 second delay between executing the restore sql and doing the disconnection logic.

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool DBHelper::ExecuteNonQuery( const wstring& sql, long delayInMilliseconds /* = 0*/ )
{
   SQLHENV env = nullptr;
   SQLHDBC dbc = nullptr;
   SQLRETURN ret = 0;
   SQLSMALLINT outstrlen = 0;
   SQLHSTMT stmt = nullptr;

   if ( !ConnectImpl( env, dbc ) )
   {
      return false;
   }

   SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbc, &stmt );

   auto sq = SQLPrepareW( stmt, ( SQLWCHAR* ) sql.c_str(), SQL_NTS);
   if ( !SQL_SUCCEEDED( sq ) )
   {
      _lastError = ExtractError( "SQLPrepare", dbc, SQL_HANDLE_DBC );
      DisconnectAndCleanup( env, dbc, stmt );
      return false;
   }
   sq = SQLExecute( stmt );

   if ( delayInMilliseconds > 0 )
   {
      // Database often stuck in "restoring..." state
      // Adding a delay after executing the restore sql, but before disconnection, seems to greatly improve things.
      std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( delayInMilliseconds ) );
   }

   if ( !SQL_SUCCEEDED( sq ) )
   {
      _lastError = ExtractError( "SQLExecute", stmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT );
      SQLFreeHandle( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt );
      SQLDisconnect( dbc );
      SQLFreeHandle( SQL_HANDLE_ENV, env );
      SQLFreeHandle( SQL_HANDLE_DBC, dbc );
      return false;
   }

   SQLFreeHandle( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt );
   SQLDisconnect( dbc );
   SQLFreeHandle( SQL_HANDLE_ENV, env );
   SQLFreeHandle( SQL_HANDLE_DBC, dbc );

   return true;
}
```

The sql that is used is:

RESTORE DATABASE [IvaraApplicationTesting] FROM  DISK = N'C:\IvaraApplicationTesting\IvaraApplicationTesting.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,
MOVE N'ivara_data' TO N'C:\IvaraApplicationTesting\IvaraApplicationTesting_data.mdf',
MOVE N'ivara_log' TO N'C:\IvaraApplicationTesting\IvaraApplicationTesting_log.ldf',
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE, RECOVERY

I've noticed the SQL_Execute returns SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO.

Just wondering if there are any ideas on why I need to introduce the delay.

Comment: The asynchronous processing must still be active.  The delay is a bit of a kluge to avoid SQL_STILL_EXECUTING checks (apparently from the ODBC documentation, is necessary even if SQLCompleteAsync return SQL_SUCCESS).  At some point, you'll determine that 3 seconds isn't long enough.  Either bump it up to 4 seconds, or check the processing state.

Comment: @Eljay - this is an interesting possibility.  I didn't think anything I was doing would be using Async.  I'm calling SQLExecute with the restore sql.